# How to properly include Android OS classes in JUnit test

Tags: java, android, junit

I have a piece of code I am working on for use with an Android App. I am trying a few things out so I have some really dirty (I.E. not well encapsulated but work) tests. The problem is I recently tried to include a test that goes over creating a model object. However, in order to play nicely with Android Activities, I am implementing Parcelable. So when I try to run my test I see...

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.os.Parcelable
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:359)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:348)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:347)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
>       ... 38 more

I tried adding the following folder to my classpath (under debug configurations in Eclipse)

```
ADT/sdk/platforms/android-10/data/android/os
```

But I still get the error. Short of creating a whole large package to run on the actual device is there a way I can include a jar or something to get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with I separated the Parcelable from the model class. Here is an example...

```
package com.gleason.apahelper.model.parcelable;
```

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.gleason.apahelper.model.Team;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

```
public class TeamParcel implements Parcelable{
private Team team;

public static TeamParcel[] getParcelable(List<Team> teams){
    TeamParcel[] parcel = new TeamParcel[teams.size()];
    for(int i = 0 ; i < teams.size(); i++){
        parcel[i] = new TeamParcel();
        parcel[i].team = teams.get(i);
    }
    return parcel;
}


public static List<Team> getTeams(TeamParcel[] parcels){
    List<Team> list = new ArrayList<Team>();
    for(TeamParcel parcel : parcels){
        list.add(parcel.team);
    }
    return list;
}
public TeamParcel(){
}

public TeamParcel(Parcel in){
    String[] data = new String[2];
    in.readStringArray(data);
    team = new Team();
    team.setTeamId(Integer.parseInt(data[0]));
    team.setTeamName(data[1]);
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeStringArray(new String[] {String.valueOf(team.getTeamId()),
            team.getTeamName()});
}
public static final Parcelable.Creator<TeamParcel> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<TeamParcel>() {
    public TeamParcel createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
      return new TeamParcel(in);
    }
    public TeamParcel[] newArray(int size) {
      return new TeamParcel[size];
    }
};


}
```

I haven't fully tested it so I am not accepting this answer but it appears to work. I would be happy to accept a better (or better explained) answer.